# ImageProvider pointing out error when running app (OSError (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2))

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I'm having problems with Assets, I put the right path for the image directory in pubspec, but even so it points out an error like the one below:

EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Cannot open file, path = 'imgteste' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      _File.open. (dart:io/file_impl.dart:356:9)

#3      FileImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:888:29)

(elided 2 frames from dart:async)

Path: imgteste
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: images/user_icon.jpg
Activating Dart DevTools...                                         4,3s
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone x86 is available at:
http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A61576%2FIAJEI80Z9QA%3D%2F

Another exception was thrown: Unable to load asset: images/user_icon.jpg

my pubspec :

assets:
- images/user_defaultp.png

my picture directory:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but check your file path name in pubspec and the path you have used in the code is correct (both should be same )

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this solution:
First create folder 'assets' and then subfolder 'images'
assest->images->user_defaultp.png

Also declare image path in pubspec.yaml as
assets:
- assets/images/logo.png

[! reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMDBO.png)